# Embedded Linux shell (BusyBox) check over list of files if they exist and run commands

Tags: linux, shell, embedded

I'm trying to download a list of files (text file, one filename per line, no spaces or newlines in the filenames), and then check for each file if it exists and run commands accordingly. the first part seems to work just fine, the file from the web server is downloaded, and the first echo outputs the filenames. but the file existence check does not work.

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -qO- http://web.server/x/files.txt | while read file
do
        echo $file
        if [ -f $file ]; then
                echo $file exists
        else
                echo $file does not exist
        fi
done
```

output when executed in a directory where the second file (temp.txt) does exist:

```
file1.tmp
 does not exist
temp.txt
 does not exist
file3.tmp
 does not exist
file4.tmp
 does not exist
```

The second file does exist, and the echo commands in the if statement apparently doesn't recognize the $file variable either.

Any help is appreciated, I tried cobbling this together with info found here. A problem might be that this is not a full linux system, but embedded Linux (OpenELEC) with BusyBox v1.22.1.

**UPDATE**: thanks to the commenters we figured out that the code as is basically works fine AS LONG as the files.txt from the web server only contains unix EOL -- it doesn't work with windows CRLF line endings.

Now how could the script be made to work regardless of the line endings in the file from the web server?

Comment: Have you tested this on a full Linux system as well to verify whether that's the problem?

Comment: Have not tried that, as I need to get this running on the embedded system.

Comment: you should try that first to help isolate the problem. I will generally make sure something runs on full linux before trying to port it.

Comment: Also, your code looks perfectly fine to me, except that you should normally do `if [ -f "$file" ]`.

Comment: @merlin2011 that won't make a difference in this case, however it is recommended, as there are no spaces or expandable characters in filenames.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I said normally.  :)

Comment: Just tried it on a CentOS 6.5 box, and the output is exactly the same -- so it doesn't work on full linux either.

Comment: @merlin2011 That's why I included "however it is recommended". ;)
@Tom Can you confirm that there are no spaces in `$file`, you can use `echo $file | wc -c` to do it.

Comment: the file on the webserver looks like this (each filename on a new line):
file1.tmp
temp.txt
file3.tmp
file4.tmp

Comment: what is the output of the character count for each file ?

Comment: hmmm, problem apparently lies with the files.txt on the webserver, if it contains windows CRLF EOL the script doesn't work. will update the question to address that issue and how to work around it. thanks for guiding me in the right direction ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dos2unix` is a utility which converts Windows line endings to Unix line endings. You can use it in your script like this:

```
wget -qO- http://web.server/x/files.txt | dos2unix | while read file
```

Or:

```
while read line; do
    ...
done < <(wget -qO- http://web.server/x/files.txt | dos2unix)
```

Comment: thanks, the first one works fine. on the busybox system the second syntax < <(...) doesn't work, btw.